# Removing characters after space in a string - R Studio data cleaning

Tags: r, regex, data-cleaning

I am attempting to clean some data in R Studio.

Here's an example of my data.

```
LSOA name:
York 009A
Wychavon 014A
Bath and North East Somerset 001A
Aylesbury Vale 008C
Central Bedfordshire 030C
```

I want to be able to remove the code from the end of each. So that the resulting data looks like this:

```
LSOA name:
York
Wychavon
Bath and North East Somerset
Aylesbury Vale 
Central Bedfordshire
```

I am quite new to regex so finding this quite difficult. From what I can tell, as there is a variable number of words before the code, a simple remove characters after a whitespace is not possible.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match one or more spaces followed by one or more digits (`\\d+`) and an upper case letter (`[A-Z]`) at the end (`$`) of the string and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
df1$name <- sub("\\s+\\d+[A-Z]$", "", df1$name)
```

-output

```
df1
#                          name
#1                         York
#2                     Wychavon
#3 Bath and North East Somerset
#4               Aylesbury Vale
#5         Central Bedfordshire
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("York 009A", "Wychavon 014A", 
"Bath and North East Somerset 001A", 
"Aylesbury Vale 008C", "Central Bedfordshire 030C")), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use lookahead `(?=\\s\\d+)`and backreference `\\1`:

```
sub("(.*)(?=\\s\\d+).*", "\\1", df1$name, perl = T)
[1] "York"                         "Wychavon"                     "Bath and North East Somerset" "Aylesbury Vale"              
[5] "Central Bedfordshire"
```

Another option is `str_extract` and the nagative character class `\\D`, which matches any char that is *not* a digit (`trimws`removes the whitespace).

```
library(stringr)
trimws(str_extract(df1$name, "\\D+"))
```